# Why my function isn't applied to every elements despite I use a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did a function to add a button and limit the characters numbers of each article that are on my website.

I just find a problem and it's that one part of the function is applied to each element (the size restriction) but the button doesn't appear on each article (take a look at the picture bellow)
[image]

That's my Javascript code where I loop over each element and add the button if the `<span>`length is bigger than my limit:

```
resize = function() {
  //allow us to limit the text length
    $('.liArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
    mySpan = $('.mySpan');
    if(mySpan.text().length>500){
      //put the read more button
      $("#readMore").removeClass("hidden");
    }
    mySpan.text(mySpan.text().substring(0,500) + '\n' + " ...");
  });
}
```

And there is the HTML code of the articles where I use class (the important things are the `<li>`and the `<button id="readMore>`):

```
<template name="article">
  <li class="liArticle">
    <div>
        <img id="pic" src= {{photo}} />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="titreArticle">{{titre}}</label>
        {{#if isOwner}}
           {{#unless wantModif}}
        <button class="delete" style="color:black">&times;</button>
        <button class="modify" style="color:black">modifier</button>
          {{/unless}}
        {{/if}}
        <p id="dateHeure"><strong>Ecrit par: {{username}} le {{date}} à {{heure}} {{lieux}} </strong></p>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="textContenu">
        <span class="mySpan">{{text}}</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="readMore" class="hidden">lire la suite </button>
    <button type="button" id="readAll" class="hidden">retourner sur le site </button>
  </li>
</template>
```

Someone can help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my Javascript ?

[EDIT] I have changed my code with your advices and now the problem is deeper in the code where I do "when we click readMore display all the text in the span" but now it doesn't display this text it only display the same that was in the first step (the limited character text) take a look

```
'click .readMore'(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const id = this._id
  const art = Articles.findOne({_id: id});
  titre =  art["titre"];
  text = art["text"];
  const photo = art["photo"];
    $(".readMore").addClass("hidden");
    mySpan.text(text);
    $("#readAll").removeClass("hidden");
window.scrollTo(0,0);
},
```

[EDIT2] Okay guys now it works so thank you to everybody who helped me ! The thing I had to change was in the first EDIT I had `mySpan.text(text);` now I putted `$('.mySpan').text(text);`because we changed that in the HTML

Comment: change `#readMore` to a class. you can only have 1 `id`. no duplicates.

Comment: thank you now the button appear on each article :)

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `readMore` to a class and look for `mySpan` and the `readMore` within the `li`:-

```
<button type="button" class="readmore hidden">lire la suite </button>
<button type="button" class="readall hidden">retourner sur le site </button>
```

.

```
resize = function() {
  //allow us to limit the text length
    $('.liArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
       mySpan = $('.mySpan', this);
       if(mySpan.text().length>500){
         //put the read more button
         $('.readmore', this).removeClass("hidden");
       }
       mySpan.text(mySpan.text().substring(0,500) + '\n' + " ...");
  });
}
```

using `$('.mySpan', this)` and `$('.readmore', this)` will target the elements within the `li` in the `each`.

Comment: Yes but I have the same problem with the @icewind solution look the Edit please

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting all spans in every loop. Just change selector to

`mySpan = $(this).find('.mySpan');`

And as @BenG noticed you should use class on button instead of id and show it like this 

`$(this).find('.readMore').removeClass('hidden');`

Comment: Thank you but I have an other problem in my code now can you help me ? 
`'click .readMore'(event) {
const id = this._id
  const art = Articles.findOne({_id: id});
text = art["text"];
$(".readMore").addClass("hidden");
mySpan.text(text);
}`as you can see when I click on the button readMore I want to display all the text but it doesn't work anymore because of `mySpan.text``

Comment: @Jerome Have you used a selector for `mySpan` from my answer?

Comment: I did the same things as you did

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this:-

```
$("#readMore").removeClass("hidden");
```

Id has to be unique otherwise it will take only the first occurrence of this id and apply the changes to it. Add some unique identifier with the id.

Also, you are creating a substring of more than 500 chars use:-

```
mySpan.text(mySpan.text().substring(0,495) + '\n' + " ...");
```

Edit:- You can do this if you have the id of the articel

```
<button type="button" id="readMore_{{id}}" class="readMore hidden">lire la suite</button>
```

Script:-

```
 resize = function() {
    //allow us to limit the text length
    $('.liArticle').each(function(i, obj) {
    mySpan = $('.mySpan');
    if(mySpan.text().length>500){
      //put the read more button
      $(this).find('.readMore').removeClass("hidden");
    }
    mySpan.text(mySpan.text().substring(0,495) + '\n' + " ...");
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advices but I still have some problems

Comment: I have modified the answer to match your needs. Please check.